# What would humanity do, if everything was invented?

Tags: humans

Today it's 23 July, year 198239811.
We have created super-computers that are sentient enough to understand every human concept beyond human capability, yet not sentient enough (or close enough) to rebel and think of deserving rights. They are producing our food, buildings and every item. Did I mention they can upgrade themselves and adjust themselves all the time to every human need? Humanity has spread along couple thousands of galaxies. We have fixed every disease and everybody finally agreed on common point (I know, I know). No wars, couple religion and peaceful ideologies to the mix. Average human lives about 230 years. We even have 18283 plans (with near 99.9% of success possibility) on what to do when Big Bang will pull all matter together.

--

For this let's assume that there are no aliens. Also, we know all atoms and molecules possible and we live across every "scientifically proven" biomass or other residential possibilities.

--

What would such society pursue? They invented everything, every movie has been recorded, every food has been created, everything is there. There's nothing to pursue. What would motivate people to learn, to teach, to obey or disobey. If everybody has "everything", what would society aim for. How would it look like? How to "disrupt" this balance (without changing points   I mentioned before)?

**TL;DR: What should humanity do, to keep it active, when everything is invented and every problem is dealt with?**

Comment: It would take a hundreds of lifespans just to understand and know everything that "humanity" has discovered thus far in even one field of science. There's no reason why people can't better themselves, learn things and experience things for themselves.

Comment: @Feyre What would motivate them? "Computers can do better". We use calculators, emulators, speech synthesizers, audio-books. Nothing seems to motivate us to use our brains, what would be motivation then?

Comment: The challenge and excitement of learning things itself.

Comment: Inventions are coming from people needs of solutions to replace or overcome something. As long as there is "need", there will be "inventions". And also there is the mishap factor. Humans evolved via hundred millions of years. You picked +200 millions from now on. We can't possibly know what will happen, but declaring 'all inventions done' can not be factual, only hypothetical or belief statement. You will need to set more specifics for your question, otherwise it will be not possible to answer.

Comment: They'll invent something else. ;)

Comment: @nzaman They won't have to, computers will.

Comment: @Sonic A.I. will most likely follow us until or death, or be our death. So whatever problem there is, it will follow us regardless how we evolve. If there will be problem, there will be solution by old relic of the past.

Comment: @Feyre I don't see people memorizing decimal tables, but I see people using calculators. I don't see people playing games, but people who play games and then record themselves. I barely see people reading books, rather they'd listen to them. I don't see the "challenge and excitement" in these days, what would make it real in next millennia's?

Comment: @DisplayName Not everyone is a 'Murican.

Comment: @DisplayName AI was not mentioned in your setup, and AI will be able to solve problems, that are defined to it. It can not deal with groundbraking changes. It can work, if you keep and isolate people from inventing. But that is alternative future and not based on current.

Comment: @DisplayName I feel sad that your surroundings don't seem to show you a more colourful view. Where I live there's people reading books, next to people that write new books. There's people playing games, door-to-door with people that make these games. Maybe have a look at [The Culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture), created by Iain Banks (mhrip) - People simply pursue something, anything. No matter if there's already been found a solution for it, because that's what people do, they create

Comment: related: Asimov wrote a nice piece called "the last question". http://multivax.com/last_question.html I think that's related and probably an answer to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [If an elder race has seen all...](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/6718/6986)

Comment: With a lifespan of 230 years, you won't even be able to watch all of the superhero/harry potter/hobbit movies and many, many reboots and offshoots that will be filmed between now and then.

Answer (score 9):

## You cannot write every book

Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Normally I would point out that your question is much too broad and a call for Idea Generation, which is not normally considered right for Worldbuilding. Please visit [the help page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to write a useful and answerable question.

However, I will make an exception in this case because of a fundamental misunderstanding you have: that "everything" can be created.

Assume you wish to write a book in English; assume you limit yourself to 100 words (that is a **really** short book); assume you can use any word you like; and assume you can put them in any order you like, as many times as you like.

How many books can you write that way?

Well, the English language contains...

> 171,476 words in current use, and 47,156 obsolete words

...[if the 20th Edition of Oxford English Dictionary is to be believed](http://171,476%20words%20in%20current%20use,%20and%2047,156%20obsolete%20words).

How many 100-word books can you write using 171,476 words?

You can write... $2,632 \cdot 10^{520}$ books.

This is an entirely mindboggling number that cannot be grasped by a human mind. Let us just say that — by way of comparison — the number of atoms in the observable universe is a mere $1\cdot10^{80}$ (approximately).

In brief this means: **humans can never create "everything"**. There is not enough material in the universe to make all of these things real.

Comment: This reminds me of the chess games problem. Just like you don't start a game with `1.a4`,you don't start a book with "Hold the newsreader's nose squarely, waiter; or friendly milk will countermand my trousers." How many *logical* books could there be?

Comment: and this is before we get onto painting every picture, carving every statue etc. Long after the "need" for labour and progress has ended, we will still have art.

Comment: You can't write every book, but every book needed. "Create me book about flying elephants". It's doable.

Comment: @Feyre Let me put it this way: not even at a 230 year life span will one person ever be able to read all the world's books **today**, nor watch all the movies, nor hear all the music/songs. Also do note that I did limit myself to one language and 100 words, less than the average SE question). Just trying to see how many **sentences**, and you will never find an end to it. I am willing to bet you that this very sentence you are reading now has never been written by a human being before, and in all probable likelihood will never be written again other than when being quoted.

Comment: @DisplayName You cannot know for certain whether a book is needed or not, or — much more important — whether it enriches humanity or not, before you write it. Which means that in order to try to write every needed/enriching book, you have to write every book. This cannot be done, **especially** since there is no upper limit to how long a book can become until you run out of "ink" and "paper".

Comment: I certainly don't question the logic of the answer. I'm just curious if it would be possible to estimate how many sufficiently distinct real books could be written.

Comment: @Feyre Well good luck in trying to define "sufficiently distinct" and "real books". But I dare posit that you will **always** fail to limit the number of possible books — to anything reasonable — based on the fact that an average novel usually ends up in the rage of 100 000 words. And since the variety of books that can be written increases **exponentially** with the number of words, you will always end up with these completely mind-boggling numbers.

Comment: @Feyre actually your example strikes me as a beautiful case of [Dadaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dada) - therefore (sadly) making it a perfectly valid example of not a *logic* book (as these presumably are limited to science rather than arts) but of a *real* book that can be enjoyed and studied by anyone wishing to indulge

Comment: @Feyre and Michael: [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/34/) has something to say on this subject.

Comment: The starting assumptions are totally unrealistic. Consider the amount of progress made in the last 200 years. Your time period is a million times longer than this. If machines can do everything as well as humans (well below another 100 years away) then humans will just pursue hobbies, sports and games or waste time online.

Comment: `-1` for answering and voting to close. One or the other is fine. The combination of both are not.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling What I had to say was too long for a comment. And I stated outright that this is an exception to the norm. The question was clearly too broad, so it had to be voted to close. But it also had another thing that warranted mentioning in that the basic premise was flawed, which — even though the question is not answerable — may be useful for others to know before they make the same flawed assumption. I argue it is a rare case that is best served by the dual action.

Comment: Also, sure $171\,476^{100} \approx 2.6 \times 10^{523}$, but most of those 100-word books would resemble [Diceware](http://www.diceware.com) passphrases, being linguistically totally meaningless. The real-world entropy of the English language is far, *far* lower than this. It's probably a more reasonable assumption that any given word can be followed by any of 100 words on average, than that any given word can be followed by any of 171k+ words on average.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well like I mentioned in comments: the average novel is 100 000 words. And if you consider serials as one work, then you can easily have millions of words for one work alone. With the exponential increase of entropy for each word that is added, we will still very quickly reach the $10^{80}$ limit.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Make the assumption that in order to make a valid sentence, any one word can be followed by at least — and no more than — 10 different other words. And suppose we limit our novels to 101 words each. That still makes for $10^{100}$ different novels. So I maintain that it simply cannot be done... we cannot write every book... we cannot compose every song... we cannot make every movie... we cannot program every game. And in either case no one person can read, listen to, watch and/or play all of this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Like others, I'd point out that the concept of running out of things to do is an oddity at best.  A classic example of something that we will never be done with is pinning down the semantics of our language.  It has been shown that, if your formal language permits all of arithmetic, the language *cannot* fully define its own semantics ([Alfred Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem)).

Phrased another way, the world of ideas is always larger than the world of reality.

In fact, to run out of things to do, one would actually have to explore why the human mind ceased to be able to come up with new ideas.  This would be a dark and insidious dystopia, because something would have had to go very very *very* wrong in a past distant generation to arrive at this point.  If you decided what went wrong to cause us to no longer come up with new ideas, then we could further discuss what humanity would be doing without those ideas.

Comment: What a wonderful phrase: *the world of ideas is always larger than the world of reality*. And there is mathematical proof for it! Love it. Also: I tried Googling it. Seems that was an original sentence, at least in the world of the Internet. :D

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Awesome, thanks!  I'm sure a poet captured the idea with even more imagination than I, but I'll happily take credit for what I can =)

Answer (score 1):

Problems do not exist "out there", waiting to be solved. A problem comes into existence when a human being looks at a situation and says/thinks to themselves "It shouldn't be this way". (source: [Landmark Advanced Course](http://www.landmarkworldwide.com/advanced-programs/the-landmark-advanced-course), proprietary course materials)

Unless you substantially re-engineer the standard human being, they are going to find (create) problems. We are problem-making machines.

Hopefully, in your future society, people are educated to create problems worth solving (as opposed to petty feuds with their neighbours over music volumes or something). Rather than inventing things for physical practical purposes, for example, if that is no longer required, perhaps they will invent things for fun. As art.

Maybe they will spend their time inventing fictional scenarios and asking each other questions about what people would do in such a fictional scenario ...

Comment: And for every living problem-making machine, there will be one processor with calculational speed of 100 * our current computation world-wide possibility. Ready to solve that problem, produce the solution on it's own.

Comment: So, how would your designated processor solve the problem you describe in your question to your satisfaction, @Display?

Answer (score 0):

I think they would continue to engage in many of the similar behaviors we do now when we have time:

1. Social Media - let's have more time to get likes.
2. Stupid Video - Anyone can fly around in their perpetual motion auto-navigation skateboard, but watch me bump my head against a door. Cats are out because they've mutated into something that truly wants nothing to do with people and won't be bothered chasing anything.
3. They'll think they can sing, well.
4. Getting back to primitive life-styles - Isn't it more fun trying to light a fire by rubbing two sticks together than using spontaneous fusion when you have nothing but time on your hands?
5. Games of chance - assuming predicting the future or time travel isn't an option.
6. Sex - who knows what bizarre forms it may take, but it's going to happen and a lot more often. That's how they got wars and violence to stop. Don't fight, have a quicky.
7. Drugs - you're not going to die and you don't have to get up and go to work. Why not?
8. Reenactments - Remember when people use to do...

Everyday probably just looks like a holiday or a weekend. We'll never get away from feeling bored, so there is going to be constant change, doing all sorts of things, having many parties about nothing.

Sleep will become the biggest past-time.

Answer (score 0):

They would enjoy life.  If you look at most people, the things they enjoy doing typically aren't inventive or creative.  Instead, there's inherent pleasure in the doing of them.

Just to take an example I'm familiar with (me, that is), I spend a lot of my non-working time doing things like hiking, biking, cross-country skiing, riding my horse, working in my garden and eating the results, and much more.  None of that's creative (well, except the cooking, sometimes :-)), but I still get a lot of pleasure from the doing.